# I copied all files from /home/user excluding .ssh folder to another server (and could use passwordless ssh into it), now ssh requires password. why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

Both servers have the same user, I use rsync and exclude the ssh folder in /home/user/ , but every time I do this (part of my new server setup pipeline) suddenly I have to start typing the password for the user, whereas before I could just ssh into the server as the user.

My question is where outside the .ssh folder but within /home/user/ are the settings getting changed?

Comment: "I could just ssh into the server as the user" - Sounds like you were using key authentication and/or the server configuration isn't identical.

Comment: How did you "copy excluding `.ssh` folder"? Please [edit] the question and post exact command(s) and/or describe your actions.

Comment: Is it possible that your sync is changing the owner or permissions on ~/.ssh?  sshd will ignore .ssh/authorized_keys if other users can write it.

Answer (score -1):

/etc/ssh/sshd.conf

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

then `sudo systemctl sshd restart`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote for this, your question does not make sense. The ONLY place outside of `~/.ssh/` which applies settings to the sshd daemon is the `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` file. If the problem is not within your `~/.ssh/` then this is the only other config which will have any effect on the service. Regardless, even if my answer is not satisfactory, it is none the less the only other possibility to effect change, short of recompiling sshd with your own desired behaviours.
Please humour me and: `diff /server1/etc/ssh/sshd.conf server2/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`